# How do I bind a Picker async?

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await

I'm loading via httpClient some values into a List. Now I want to bind this List to a Picker. But the Picker is empty.

I have a class "Trade" with different items, e.g. title.

The ViewModel (FirmsViewModel) has the following code:

```
 public async Task GetTradesData()
        {
            var tradeList = await App.RestService.GetTradesAsync(true);

            Trades = new ObservableCollection<Trade>(tradeList);
        }
```

The "Trades" List is filled. Till this point it seems to be working.

In my Page.cs file I have the following code:

```
public FirmsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            viewModel = new FirmsViewModel();
            BindingContext = viewModel;
        }

protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            await viewModel.GetTradesData();
        }
```

The XAML of the picker:

```
 <Picker SelectedIndex="{Binding TradesSelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Trades}"
                ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding title}"
                Margin="0,15,0,0"
                Title="Select a Trade">
</Picker>
```

If you are running the code, the Picker is always empty. Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm that `GetTradesData()`gettes called? And could you please add the definition of the `Trades`-Property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be straight forward:

1. Make sure that you fire the `PropertyChanged` event after setting the `Trades` property
2. Make sure that this event is fired on the UI Thread

So if assuming your declaration of `Trades` looks like:

```
public ObservableCollection<Trade> Trades { get; private set; }
```

You could just call. `RaisePropertyChanged("Trades");` (or whatever the equivalent is in your ViewModel type) right after assigning it in `GetTradesData()`

Alternatively you could change your declaration of your property:

```
private ObservableCollection<Trade> _trades;
public ObservableCollection<Trade> Trades
{
    get => _trades;
    set
    {
        _trades = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Trades");
    }
}
```

Or what I personally would prefer, is to simply initialize the ObservableCollection from the beginning and simply adding the items to it in `GetTradesData()`:

```
public ObservableCollection<Trade> Trades { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Trade>();
```

and in `GetTradesData()`:

```
foreach (var trade in tradeList)
    Trades.Add(trade);
```